# Any way to ensure XML and JSON documents marshall and unmarshall correctly with different libraries/languages?

Tags: xml, json, type-conversion, jax-rs

I am trying to see if in 2014, we're at a place where returning a JSON or XML document via a rest service from say, JAX-RS spring implementation will be compatible when used by another library possibly in another language? If I write a Windows mobile .net client that consumes my Java JAX-RS api, will the way the JAX-RS returns the json (and/or xml) convert correctly in the .net client? Or are there issues with various languages and libraries?

I ask this because in one case in particular, we return a collection of items, and in XML it will result in this:

```
<items>
  <item attr="value">another value</item>
  <item attr="value2">another value2</item>
</items>
```

The resulting JSON looks something like:

```
"items": [
   {"attr":"value","value":"another value"},
   {"attr":"value2", "value":"another value2"}
  ]
```

However, in using online xml to json and json to xml.. when I paste the above XML and get the above json conversion.. then past the json above into the json to xml converter.. the xml is different.. it becomes:

```
<items>
  <item>
    <element attr="value">another value</element>
    <element attr="value2">another value2</element>
  </item>
</items>
```

My concern is that on our service side code.. we use a library to take the incoming xml or json and turn it in to an object. If the above XML were to be sent due to some client side marshalling it like that.. our server side would throw exceptions.. not able to handle the  type.

I also see in some cases JSON that converts xml attributes into "@attrName":"value".

So.. is there any way to ensure that the json and xml we return is "correct" and can be read/parsed by any client? Are there some things we should document with regards to the *type* of json being returned that would give hints on how to properly configure a different library to make sure to marshal the same json from the data? I see for example in the Eclipse Moxy, there are some configurations that can be set.

In my past, I simply used Jersey with JAX-RS and it handled json and xml for me.. I never thought about issues like different consumer libraries converting what my JAX-RS sends out into something not compatible, especially in a case where for example they use our XSDs to generate POJOs in their language/library of choice, that may not match with what our XSD to POJO generates.